# assign context of a .csv file, line by line as a variable into a linux command script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, elasticsearch, variables

I have a `.csv` file that contains 2500 unique request id like "4485-182-65846".
I want to run a elasticsearch query command that contain this request Id.
my query be like:

```bash
curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200/_search?pretty -d '

{
     "query": {
             "match": {
                "request_id": "$VARIABLE(contents of the file)"
               }
         }
}' > answer.csv
```

Now I want to put every unique id into a VARIBALE and run the query to answer them in a specific file

I would appreciate any help.

I tried this code but did not answer

```bash
request_id=(cat file.csv)

for i in request_id;

do

curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200/_search?pretty -d '

{
     "query": {
             "match": {
                "request_id": "$i"
               }
         }
}' > answer.csv
```

Comment: (1) Your `request_id` is an array with two elements: _cat_  and _file.csv_. However, you never actually use this array (2) Your loop is executed only once, with `i` set to the string `request_id`.

Comment: what should I do now?

Comment: One more point: `$i` does not get expanded, because it is between single quotes. Honestly, I don't understand your code, for instance I don't understand, what you want to loop over, so it's hard to recommend anything. For instance, how are the "unique ids" stored in the file? Is it **really** a CSV file, i.e. according to the CSV standard? What is the general format of such an id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your attention and answers, this worked for me:

```
VAR=$(cat file1.txt)

for i in $VAR;

do 

curl --user userpasswrd:password -XGET "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'

{
     "query": {
             "match": {
                "log.request_id": '$i'
               }
         }
}' >> answer.csv
```

note: I had to save the file1.txt with UTF8 encoding and put all request id between double quotation

Answer (score 1):

`jq` is a good tool for manipulating JSON. For example, assuming the contents of your file.csv are:

```
4485-182-65846
4485-182-65847
4485-182-65848
4485-182-65849
4485-182-65850
```

You can generate JSON using these values via:

```
$ json_template='{ "query": { "match": { "request_id": "$id" }}}'
$ while read -r id ; do req=$(echo $json_template | jq --arg jqid "$id" '.query.match.request_id |= $jqid'); echo "$req" ; done <file.csv
```

Generated JSON looks like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "request_id": "4485-182-65846"
    }
  }
}
```

You could then use the JSON in your HTTP query by changing the `while read...` loop to:

```
while read -r id ; do req=$(echo '{ "query": { "match": { "request_id": "$id" }}}' | jq --arg jqid "$id" '.query.match.request_id |= $jqid'); curl -XGET https://127.0.0.1:9200/_search?pretty -d "$req" ; done <file.csv
```

(Note, your code has additional oddities aside from those identified by @user1934428.  Your GET URL has no `https` protocol.)